# My http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ is opening a blank page

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

When I clicked on *MySQL "admin"* on XAMPP control panel, it opens a blank webpage. I searched for a solution everywhere, but I couldn't find one.

[image: capture]

Comment: Is the web server running? The Apache??

Comment: Yes. The web server running the Apache

Comment: If you just run `http://localhost` does that work?